# Using USE in ColdFusion with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Postgres doesn't have the `USE` directive, unlike SQL Server or MySQL. There is the `\c <database>` command, but that only works in the `psql` REPL. Is there an alternative to `USE` that can be used with `cfquery` in Postgres? We would be using this with CF 11.

Comment: Hmmm... why are you using the "USE" command in your cf queries - do you use it to switch between DBs?  You could of course switch the "datasource" attribute out using a variable and accomplish the same thing no?

Comment: There were choices made in the beginning of this app that was .... unfortunate. One result was that we have many, many databases and someone who is not me does not want to setup a different datasource for each one.

Comment: Yeah - totally with you on that :) Not a posgres guy Randy - but I'll ask my team.. maybe someone knows.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot change the database after the connection has been made (at least, not with the main bindings, including the official `libpq`; `psql`'s `\c` command will create a new connection behind the scenes). But, there is a (somewhat) similar concept, which may fill your needs: create multiple [schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html), instead of multiple databases. Then, you can switch between them with the [`SET search_path ...` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html). (In MySQL, schemas and databases are synonyms).

Comment: that sounds promising Pozs - though it means Randy will likely have to pick his poison - ether create a bunch of schemas or create a bunch of DSNs.

Comment: The CF Admin API might ease the DSN creation.

Comment: I didn't realize other methods were available for creating datasources.

Comment: Here's an example using mySQL http://swalsh.org/blog/2013/03/20/programmatically-creating-new-datasource-in-coldfusion/ and the official Adobe docs http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html